# What is the factor in the collapse option in the decimate modelifier?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I get it roughly, but there's no response on the program.

[image]

Comment: Will do something only if the weights differ. If all equal, nothing.

Comment: thank you. After applying weight paint, the mesh seems to decrease depending on the value.